# three.js canvasrenderer very slow

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl, 360-panorama-viewer

I have this panoramic viewer:
http://ulrichbangert.de/heimat/Goslar_Kirchen/2016-06-30_Marktkirche_Panorama.html
Initially I used the WebGL renderer but as it didn't work on my mobile I switched to the canvas renderer. Works in Opera on my mobile but the performance is very poor: Automatic scrolling is extremely slow. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Canvas renderer is always going to be slower than webgl. Maybe using slower resolution images could speed it up? Other than that I don't see any way to speed up the canvas renderer.

Comment: Using smaller images for mobile will speed it up a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. In the meantime I've given up this script and found a better one: Pannellum. This features a CSS3 fallback and works fine in the Opera of my mobile.